# Signing up for object created event

Tags: c#, events, new-operator

Is it possible to sign up for the event that fires when the object of the specific type is created, not modifying the object?
for example, signing for this event of Label type fires it when every instance of Label is created (passing the instance of Label as parameter)

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 3):

This would be best accomplished using a Factory pattern.  If you wrap the creation of your Label objects in a LabelFactory, then the Label Factory could also expose an event that gets fired every time an object is created.

Something like this:

```
public class LabelFactory    
{    
    public Label GetLabel()  {...}    

    public event LabelEventHandler LabelCreated;
}
```

Comment: The Factory is a good solution, but not in the case when Labels are created by Windows Forms Disigner

Comment: Can you move the Label creation into your own code?  Functionally, it should be the same to create it in your code, where you can use the Factory method.

Answer (score 1):

Not without modifying the object in question to fire an event in their constructor.

@Adrian's solution is a good compromise as long as you always go through the factory to get a new instance; however, if you instantiate outside of the factory then no event would be fired.