# After Creating a Control, automatically add it to specific panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, event-handling

I have UserControls that are "Buttons" for Menu purposes. Those Buttons shall automatically add to the right Panel.

So basically, if I write:

```
MenueButton button1 = new MenueButton();
```

the button shall automatically be added to MenuePanel on GUI Form. (Maybe Some easy action handler?)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you are searching for `MenuPanel.Controls.Add(button1)`

Comment: no, because it shall do it without me pointing this out, it shall automatically add the Button to that panel. i would love to just say "go to panel1" in constructor of MenueButton but thats not possible ;)

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: well, i tried to describe it well... i just want to do what is above.. create a button, and like an "onChange" event, it shall automatically, add to where i want it to go. like "onCreateMenueButton" ...

Comment: You'll end up needing to create a factory that creates your MenueButtons and then fires an event after they've been created. There's no way to magically know in code that an object of some type has been created. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396203/signing-up-for-object-created-event

Comment: dont know how people come up with that magic stuff, i just asked how to do it, and if there is like an action to use or to create that does what i want, that what you posted looks interesting,.. but dont know why all think i talk about magic -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
 MenueButton button1 = CreateButton();
 button1.Click+=...

 MenueButton button2 = CreateButton();
 button2.Text="ABC";

 MenueButton CreateButton()
 {
   MenueButton b= new MenueButton();
   panel.Controls.Add(b);
   return b;
 }
```

This way the CreateButton function creates and automatically adds the button to the panel and you can use the newly created button in your code

If you want to do the same thing to the buttons you can add parameters to your function

```
MenueButton button1 = CreateButton("Button 1 Text");
button1.Click+=... 

MenueButton button2 = CreateButton("XYZ");


MenueButton CreateButton(string buttonText)
{
    MenueButton b= new MenueButton();
    b.Text = buttonText;
    panel.Controls.Add(b);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: well but that way, i cant name the button. the purpose is, to just add the button like normal, and add click listeners and stuff, so hmm..

Comment: (what i meant with naming is for exampe "b")

Comment: You can do that of course.You have the newly created buttons... button1.Text="xyz"

Comment: lol sorry had completly overlooked that example use above the function ... xD ... now that i'm at home and read it again, it makes more sense.. thanks for that one :) PS: is it possible to name the function all the same, if the type MenueButton is diffrent for that way? (like normal functions) that would be awesome, will test it tomorrow